# Administrative rights are required to profile IIS -dot trace

Tags: azure, dottrace

I'm trying to profile a remote Azure web site using dotTrace Perfomance standalone program, but I get "Administrative rights are required to profile IIS" error message under "Application options" when connect to Remote Computer URL, I running dottrace in a Windows 7 computer and using "run as administrator " option.

Any idea what the problem could be?

Answer (score 0):

If you work with Azure Virtual Machine where you launch IIS and your application, you can either install dotTrace and then profile everything locally on the virtual machine, or copy remote agent there and then profile from the local machine remotely. 
If you have Azure Website, then it will be impossible to profile it via dotTrace.